# Orchard Core No Page Content Type

Tags: orchardcms

I'm looking to use Orchard for a CMS project, I've setup my project via

```
dotnet new occms --framework netcoreapp3.1
```

and went through all the setup for my site.

According to [this](https://docs.orchardcore.net/projects/O1/en/latest/Documentation/Adding-Pages-to-Your-Site/) I would expect to be able to add a new page but I don't see any option that looks like that.

If I go into my content types, I don't see any that I could be able to create. Have I missed something in the setup here?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, the reason I didn't have a 'page' content type is because I didn't select a recipe when creating the site -

[image]

I recreated my site with the Blog recipe and have the Page content type now. For people coming in the future, the page content type is built like this...

[image]

[image]